# Singular values of block lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, block-matrices, singular-values

Given a fat matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (where $m<n$) with singular values $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_m$, can I express the singular values $\tilde{\sigma}_1, \dots, \tilde{\sigma}_{m+n}$ of the following block lower triangular matrix

$$T = \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ A & I \end{pmatrix}$$

in terms of the singular values of $A$? Or can I give some upper bounds on the singular values of $T$?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

I think I got a solution myself: on a standard textbook on matrix analysis I found the property $ \sigma_i(C) -  \sigma_i(B) \leq \Vert C - B \Vert  $ for all $i$ with $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Now, defining $C = T$ and $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ A & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ we have $C - B = I$ and $\sigma_{max}(B) = \sigma_{max}(A)$. Since $I$ has norm 1, then, we have

$$ \sigma_{max}(T)  =  \sigma_{max}(C) \leq  1 + \sigma_{max}(A).$$

Am I forgetting anything? It looks too beautiful to be true.

Comment: I think I got a solution myself: on a standard textbook on matrix analysis I found the property $ \sigma_i(C) -  \sigma_i(B) \leq \Vert C - B \Vert  $ for all $i$ with $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Now, defining $C = T$ and $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ A & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ we have $C - B = I$ and $ \sigma_{max}(B) = \sigma_{max}(A)$. Since $I$ has norm 1, then, we have

$$ \sigma_{max}(T)  =  \sigma_{max}(C) \leq  1 + \sigma_{max}(A).$$

Am I forgetting anything? It looks too beautiful to be true.

Comment: Feel free to edit that in your question.

Comment: @Argyll what should I edit?

Comment: Your question changed to helping you to understand a particular line of reasoning right? So it's best that you update your question accordingly by editing what you commented into the main body of your question. (If ppl already answered, you should highlight what is edited. This doesn't apply to you atm.)

Comment: Try to compute the characteristic polynomial. You should obtain the exact singular values.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo why? The eigenvalues of $T$ are all 1, but the eigenvalues not.

Comment: Eigenvalues of $T T^\top$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $$TT^{\top} - Is = \begin{pmatrix} (1-s)I & A^{\top} \\ A & ((1-s)I + AA^{\top } \end{pmatrix}.$$ 

With the Schur Decomposition, we have

$$\text{det}(TT^{\top}) = \text{det}((1-s)I)\,\text{det}((1-s)I + AA^{\top} - A \frac{1}{1-s} I A^{\top})) $$

which can be written as

$$ \text{det}(TT^{\top}) = (1-s)^n \, \text{det}((1-s) I + (1- \frac{1}{1-s})AA^{\top}) $$

and then

$$ \text{det}(TT^{\top}) = (1-s)^n \,(1- \frac{1}{1-s})^m \text{det}((- \frac{(1-s)^2}{s}) I + AA^{\top}) $$

(... continue in next comment)

Comment: and defining $\lambda = \frac{(1-s)^2}{s}$ we have that $\lambda = \sigma^2(A)$.

Now, $s$ can be calculated backwards with $\sigma^2(A)$. 

I checked it with Matlab and it seems to be correct. However, I feel the reasoning I do is not very precise. Are there any mistakes?

Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: @Trb2 I obtained the same (or close). I am not very happy with it either. Please consider editing your question again and including the work in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound is trivial since

$$
\sigma_{\max}(B) = \|B\|_2 = \|I + E \|_2 \le 1 + \|E\|_2 = 1 + \|A\|_2 = 1 + \sigma_{\max}(A).
$$